# Is $\cos(11^\circ)$ constructible?

Tags: geometric-construction

I'm trying to prove whether $\cos(11^\circ)\over \sqrt{1+\sin(15^\circ)}$ is constructible. I suspect it is not, and would like to use the triple angle identity to use RRT and prove there is no constructible root, but to do this I'd need $\cos(33^\circ)$, of which I don't know the exact value. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: The answer is no by the [Gauss-Wantzel theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_polygon#Conditions_for_constructibility).

Comment: The answer in the linked question is more complicated than what is needed for this specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Famously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection#Proof_of_impossibility) the angle of 20 degrees is not constructible. Since $20=10\times 2$ and $2=90-8\times 11$, this means that angle of 11 degrees is also not constructible.